# Mac shell script to extract audio from video files

Tags: macos, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that will extract the audio from all the movie files in a folder.

**audio_extracter.sh**

```
for f in *; do
    if  [ "$f" != "audio_extracter.sh" ]; then
        /usr/bin/avconvert --source "$f" --output */Converted/"$f" --audioTrack -af aac
        echo "$f converted"
    else
        echo "problems"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

It's spitting back `avconvert is a command line application that will transcode a source or group of sources to create a destination file output...`

Also, if possible the script should find out the format of the audio in the video and extract it as such, without converting it to a different different format (at the moment I think I'm forcing it to convert to AAC).

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

`-acodec copy` extracts audio without re-encoding in ffmpeg:

```
for f in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec copy "${f%mkv}aac"; done
```

You can see the formats of the audio streams with `ffmpeg -i input.mkv`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use mencoder, then try this. It works for me. (video format like mkv, mp4, flv, rmvb all works)

```
mencoder -oac mp3lame -ovc copy -of video_file -o audio_file.mp3
```